# how to validate spring model object with different attribute requirements different method calls?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-validator

we are using single model class in spring controller say

```
Student(id,firstname,lastname);
```

Now my controller have two methods

1. get student details where we pass Student object with id only.(only Id require)
2. update student details with all details id,firstname,lastname (where we use id for reference to update names)

in both controller methods I want to use spring validator so how can I write validated method for both controller methods as I required only id attribute to get student details and in other I want all three attributes to updated student details.

we are not using spring boot.

Comment: Question: why pass the entire object with only the id? If you are getting a student by id, just pass the id and return the Student.

Comment: A get request in general never has  Requestbody. Use get/students/1 to get the Student with id 1

Comment: @armandino ..  here I just gave example my purpose is I want to get model object validated in different way in different method

Answer (score 0):

I always use dtos (data transfer Objects) for models that are sent by the client and separate models for responses.
That has many advantages. The incoming api models are decoupelt from the models that are used in your application. In addition, with the dto you just provide a model with the minimum of attributes a client may send to the api. And to adress your question you can verify them separatere.
I don‘t think you want your client to update the students id. So for your model use a dto that has the same attributes like a full student object but without the id Field.